# Convert function into class Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm having some issues regarding classes in Python because I'm in the need of refactoring some code.

The problem I'm facing is I have to refactor multiple similar scripts, so I decided to use Python classes but I have the following question

Say we have these two similar codes that need refactoring:

```py
name = "Peter" 
print(f"Bye! {name}"}
name.replace("e", "a")
print(f"Bye! {name} **replaced**"}
```

```py
name = "Lisa" 
print(f"Hi! {name}"}
name.replace("e", "a")
print(f"Hi! {name}"}
```

So a Python class:

```py
class Greetings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = name

    def say_hi_and_replace(self, name):
        if name == "Lisa":
            print(f"Hi! {name}"}
        else:
            print(f"Hi! {name}"}
        self.name = self.name.replace("e", "a")


    def say_goodbye(self, name):
        if name == "Lisa":
            print(f"Bye! {name}"}
        else:
            print(f"Bye! {name} **replaced**"}
```

Is there a better way to write this code? I'm sure there is.

Edit: Besides using ternary operators like Klaud suggested correctly.

```py
    def say_goodbye(self, name):
        print(f"Bye! {name}"} if name == "Lisa" else print(f"Bye! {name} **replaced**"}
```

Edit: Sorry there was a typo in the "Bye!"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the decision to use `"Hi"` instead of `"Bye"` really a simple as checking if `name == "Lisa"` or not?

Comment: The last method could be shortened by 3 lines.

Comment: @KlausD. Heh heh...the case always happens...

Comment: @chepner yes, it's a simple as that

Comment: @KlausD thanks for your input but I'm not looking for ternary operators.

Comment: No, you can literally remove three lines, leave the 4th intact, and it will work as before.

Comment: It is not clear what the semantic difference between `self.name` and `name` is. The meaning of the concepts influences the design of your classes, and such ambiguity will inevitably result in a flawed design. Others have already suggested ways to improve the code, but to get a design requires complete clarity of the rules.

Comment: Look carefully at your use of the ternary operator. Whether or not `name` is Lisa, you print `Bye! {name}`.